# VS Code connect to WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, fail with error: Could not fetch remote environment

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote, wsl-2

A few days ago I was working just fine with VS Code connected to WSL Ubuntu 20.04, then I did some updating on WSL, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and VS Code and now I can not connect to WSL 20.04, and I always got those two messages, even when no folder/workspace is selected/open.

Could not fetch remote environment

Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Connection error: Unauthorized client refused.)

When I try to open a folder it shows the folder structure but it always said that: The path does not exists. And does not show any file in it but I can follow the folder structure up and down just fine.

And on the other hand if I launch WSL with an older Ubuntu 18.04 distro, it works just fine.

I imagine there is some security setting or access list that is wrong, but I can not figure it out, and web searching has not help either.

Any idea what to do to get it working again ?.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same error.
And solved it by just shutting down the wsl using command

`wsl --shutdown`

Comment: Well, that did not work in my case. Even restarting the computer did not solved anything.

Comment: This worked for me and then I followed the wsl --shutdown command with the command wsl --update.

Comment: worked here. wsl --shutdown followed by wsl to start the os again.

Comment: this worked and then I needed to reinstall the WSL extension. :)

Answer (score 11):

Seems things got messed up with the update. Fixed it by reinstalling the `Remote WSL extension: ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl` and reloading as you will be instructed to do.

Before this though, I deleted (rm -rf) the contents of /home/<your_username>/.vscode-server/ bin/ and data/

Comment: The removal of previous .vscode* directories is the most likely solution for this issue.

Comment: tried all the proposals, but nothing worked. also reinstalled the remote extensions and rm the .vscode-server as here mentioned without success. but after reseting this extension "ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack" to an older version and  updating the extension, it worked again.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried these methods but it doesn't work:

- `wsl --shutdown`
- Reinstall VScode
- Remove `.vscode-server` in WSL (`rm -rf ~/.vscode-server`)

Finally I found the problem, the problem was with the latest version of the WSL extension, downgrading the WSL extension worked for me.

I downgraded the extension version from v0.79.5 to 0.79.4, and after reloading the window everything was back to normal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If anyone wondering how to uninstall
`rm ~/.vscode-server` inside wsl

Comment: For anyone who doesn't seem to find it working. Make sure you **close all the VS code instances**. I tried this solution once it worked fine, the second time it didn't. Turns out according to a GitHub Issues you have to close all the vs code instances, even though you already run `wsl --shutdown` it's not enough.

Answer (score 5):

Lowering down the version of Remote WSL extension: ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
worked out for me.There might be some issues with the latest version.

Comment: Worked for me, as well. "Visual Studio Code Remote - WSL" version 0.58.4 did not work for me. 0.85.3 works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Another (additional) symptom to check: Can WSL connect to the internet (eg via `apt update`)?

I had compressed my AppData folder, including `C:\Users\<yourname>\AppData\Local\Temp` and this somehow broke the connection between WSL and the outer world. Uncompressing the Temp folder solved the problem for me.

Comment: Search for the `%temp%` directory, go to properties -> general -> advanced -> uncheck compress contents to save disk space. I also needed a system restart but after that, it was working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after updating the version(1.52.1). I did uninstall the ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl and installed it again and shutdown the WSL and close the vscode. Then started the WSL and open the VS-code again solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me on Win10:

opens Ubuntu CLI -> type in `code .`

It'll download the VSCode server and then open VSCode itself with no errors.

I tried the same on CMD or Powershell but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else run into this problem. The way I solved was to remove all the .vscode* folders/files on the WSL filesystem. Apparently something got screw up on the upgrade.

I have not test it fully, because I moved to directly using a remote ssh agent on the Test system. But it seems to work, as I can now open the wsl window and it does not report any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update
```

shoud work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem today, my solution was to rollback to previous VScode version. I know there might be multiple root causes, this is one of the them.

Answer (score 0):

For me, turning off the proxy will work.

[image]

or add `127.0.0.1` in the exception list.

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows OS** restarting the computer can usually resolve strange issues.

Because sometimes there maybe other processes still using the files or connection.

Answer (score -3):

Same problem, just quite the proxy software (Charles etc.) and restart the vscode, it will work fine

Comment: In my case there was no proxy software, just WSL and VSC with a bunch of extensions.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30254219)