# Vscode does not start and cannot connect to WSL

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, subsystem

I'm using vscode in Ubuntu WSL, it was working fine a couple of hours ago and suddenly stopped working as I started writing js.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling vscode but that does not work and an error : *Unable to locate package code*  appears when I try to purge.

When connecting vscode to wsl remotely error appears as follows:

```
 2020-09-30 09:20:11.585] Resolving wsl+Ubuntu, resolveAttempt: 1
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.625] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (Ubuntu)
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.625] Extension version: 0.44.5, Windows build: 19041. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.756] Probing if server is already installed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e sh -c "[ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a ] && printf found || ([ -f /etc/alpine-release ] && printf alpine-; uname -m)"
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.886] Probing result: found
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.886] Server install found in WSL
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.887] Launching C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a stable .vscode-server 0  ' in c:\Users\divya\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5}
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.996] Setting up server environment: Looking for /home/dgoel/.vscode-server/server-env-setup. Not found.
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.996] WSL version: 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft Ubuntu
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.996] Starting server: /home/dgoel/.vscode-server/bin/e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a/server.sh  --port=0 --use-host-proxy --fileWatcherPolling=0 
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.996] /mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts/wslServer.sh: 63: /home/dgoel/.vscode-server/bin/e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a/server.sh: not found
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.997] VS Code Server for WSL closed unexpectedly.
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.997] For help with startup problems, go to
[2020-09-30 09:20:11.997] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
```

here's the debug report from wsl ubuntu:

```
VSCODE_WSL_DEBUG_INFO=true code .
+ COMMIT=e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a
+ APP_NAME=code
+ QUALITY=stable
+ NAME=Code
+ DATAFOLDER=.vscode
+ realpath /mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin
+ VSCODE_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code
+ ELECTRON=/mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe
+ IN_WSL=false
+ [ -n Ubuntu ]
+ IN_WSL=true
+ [ true = true ]
+ export WSLENV=ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE/w:
+ wslpath -m /mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js
+ CLI=C:/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js
+ WSL_EXT_ID=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
+ ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 /mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe C:/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js --locate-extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
+ cat /tmp/remote-wsl-loc.txt
+ WSL_EXT_WLOC=c:\Users\divya\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5
+ [ -n c:\Users\divya\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5 ]
+ wslpath -u c:\Users\divya\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5
+ WSL_CODE=/mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts/wslCode.sh
+ /mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts/wslCode.sh e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a stable /mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe code .vscode .
+ [ -z .vscode ]
+ echo .vscode
+ sed -e s/.vscode/.vscode-server/g
+ DATAFOLDER=.vscode-server
+ VSCODE_REMOTE_BIN=/home/dgoel/.vscode-server/bin
+ AUTHORITY=wsl+default
+ [ Ubuntu ]
+ AUTHORITY=wsl+Ubuntu
+ [ ! -d /home/dgoel/.vscode-server ]
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts/wslCode.sh
+ /mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts/wslDownload.sh e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a stable /home/dgoel/.vscode-server/bin
+ [ ! -d /home/dgoel/.vscode-server/bin/e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a ]
+ RC=0
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts/wslCode.sh
+ VSCODE_CLIENT_COMMAND=/mnt/c/Users/divya/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe VSCODE_CLIENT_COMMAND_CWD=/mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts VSCODE_CLI_AUTHORITY=wsl+Ubuntu /home/dgoel/.vscode-server/bin/e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a/bin/code .
/mnt/c/Users/divya/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.5/scripts/wslCode.sh: 53: /home/dgoel/.vscode-server/bin/e5e9e69aed6e1984f7499b7af85b3d05f9a6883a/bin/code: not found
+ exit 127
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to set up your WSL again or upgrade to WSL2. Here is a helpful link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Or try this link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial#:~:text=Run%20Terminal%20%3E%20New%20Terminal%20(Ctrl,VS%20Code%20running%20on%20Windows.
It's mostly for running Python on vscode, but it might work if you follow the 'Intergrated Terminal' steps.

Comment: Yep setting up WSL again does solve the problem. Although, I'm more curious about why it might have happened in the first place.

Comment: I'm not really sure, your error code seems hard to configure. Maybe WSL Ubuntu was not your default distribution, but don't take my word for it. As long as it works.

Comment: For me it was not able to resolve authority (as per error message). 
Following steps to solved the problem for me.

1) Turn off  windows feature `windows subsystem for Linux`
2) restart computer
3) Turn  it on again
4) restart computer

Answer (score 7):

Maybe more simple than the accepted answer, I was able to solve the issue by:

1. start vscode in Windows
2. update the remote-wsl extension
3. close vscode
4. open WSL
5. start vscode from WSL

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For me what worked was to invoke vscode a couple of times from inside wsl, first time it installed vscode server, the second time I just typed `code`, this errored the vscode wsl extension, closed window and retried with `code .` worked. I guess it needs an explicit reference of what to open.

Comment: Also you might want to downgrade wsl extension version.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue after updating VSCode, I guess.
When I **reinstalled the remote-wsl extension & restarted VSCode**, the problem was still existing.

Afterwards I did the following:

- restarting the WSL by executing `wsl --shutdown` inside a windows command line (PowerShell or Command Prompt)
- opening ubuntu again (I also did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` at this point)
- navigating to the project folder and opening VSCode from there (`code .`)

---

This might be related: [VS Code connect to WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, fail with error: Could not fetch remote environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125085/vs-code-connect-to-wsl-ubuntu-20-04-lts-fail-with-error-could-not-fetch-remote)

Comment: This worked for me. Also make sure that WSL extension is installed: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was even simpler:

I closed WSL session and from Powershell, I did

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Restarted WSL and now Code works fine.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I solved it just making a rollback of the previews version (Image below).
Also do a:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me--
Follow this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial
Skip the Python development part if you don't want it then go to the Run in WSL part and run: 'code .' to install the VS code server.

Then open VS Code and choose new WSL window select your folder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32322448)

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue when i Updated VS code from the GUI. After that I couldn't start it from WSL2.

What fixed it for me was to also update VS code from WSL.

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

I suspect that something broke because I updated VS Code through the VS code GUI instead of through apt.

Answer (score 0):

First try should be update WSL, I do not know why is not listed here.

Run in a powershell:

```
wsl --update
```

I also tried:

- Uninstall last Win11 updates (did not work)
- Choose a previous VSCode WSL plugin version (did not work)
- Updating the Debian distro (did not work)
- Unregister and install the distro (after wsl --update) (WORKS...but IMO was the wsl update what make it work)

Answer (score -1):

This command works for me

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Comment: Would be great if you add some description or links related to this command!