# Error: EIO: i/o error, scandir and npm config

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-20.04, nvm

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on WSL2 and out of nowhere, I get this error upon starting up my shell.

```
Error: EIO: i/o error, scandir '/mnt/c/Users/computer'
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v14.0.0 --silent` to unset it.
```

So, I tried looking up the EIO i/o error, but no dice. There was a [solution for the npm config prefix problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option), but instead I ran into the EIO i/o error again. I attempted using `nvm` to reinstall v14.0.0 but that just output the error lines above. I reinstalled nvm and let it install 14.0.0 but the error persisted.

I am able to use node, but trying to use npm gives the EIO error.

What do I do?

Comment: This problem has somehow disappeared sometime over the past year and I have no idea why. Sorry to be a DenverCoder9.

Comment: I intermittently got similar issues. It looked similar to a WSL mounting issue as restarting WSL with `wsl --shutdown` fixed the issue, but only for a while. Turns out my problem was only in VSCode and was fixed by [reinstalling an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65468055/690188).

Answer (score 4):

From [this blog post](https://www.turek.dev/posts/fix-wsl-file-permissions/):

> The short version is to add this section to your WSL instance’s `/etc/wsl.conf` (the file probably does not exist, just create it):

```
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
```

> #### What it Does
>
> You can read the “official” Microsoft documentation on their [Dev Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/) but here is my explanation line-by-line:
>
> - The `automount` section changes the settings for drives that are automounted under `/mnt`
> - The `enabled` key is probably unnecessary but it explicitly turns on automounting (default is `true`)
> - The `options` key is a bit more interesting:
>
>   - `metadata` turns on a mostly parallel of file permission metadata that allows WSL file permissions changes to be persisted. It partially affects the underlying Windows permissions; for more details see the Dev Blog link above.
>   - `umask` value masks out (i.e. unsets) the *group* and *others* write bit for both files and directories
>   - `fmask` value masks out the *group* and *others* execute bit for just files
>
> Files should now show up with a comfortable permission setting of 0644 and directories with 0755 if they’re mounted under `/mnt`.

**Don't forget to restart after change.**